# Transforming xml using xsl for integrating systems

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, integration, transformation

Hi I'm trying to get this xml transformed into the correct format using xsl. I am new to xsl and am having problems. I need to import the xml to a database through an application.

I don't need all the attributes from the notification. I have tried the for-each tag in the xsl. This loops through the items but I only want to select a couple of them and then add in the other data myself like max:ponum, max:DOROLLOVER.

xml to transform:

```
<Notification>
    <item name="NotificationName" type="Standard">CRHWTL01 Run Hours</item>
    <item name="NotificationDescription" type="Standard">wind turbine location 01 run hours</item>
    <item name="NotificationState" type="Standard">Trend</item>
    <item name="StartTime" type="Standard">10/1/2014 4:35:00 PM</item>
    <item name="EndTime" type="Standard">1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM</item>
    <item name="TriggerTime" type="Standard">10/1/2014 5:05:00 PM</item>
    <item name="Priority" type="Standard">Low</item>
    <item name="Target" type="Standard">\\maximo\Turbines\Turbine1</item>
    <item name="State" type="Standard">Trend</item>
    <item name="NotificationInstanceID" type="Standard">1</item>
    <item name="NotificationUniqueID" type="Standard">e4472d26-5366-4e57-bc7c-1af3beb50949</item>
    <item name="\\Turbine1|Turbine OK Hours Status" 
    type="AFAttribute">19850</item>
</Notification>
```

Desired format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncMXMETERDATA xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" creationDateTime="2008-09-29T02:49:45" baseLanguage="string" transLanguage="string" messageID="string" maximoVersion="string">
    <MXMETERDATASet>
      <METERDATA action="Delete" relationship="string" ForInsert="string" transLanguage="string">
        <CHANGEDATE changed="false">2008-11-15T16:52:58</CHANGEDATE>
        <DOROLLOVER changed="true">false</max:DOROLLOVER>
        <INSPECTOR changed="true">string</INSPECTOR>
        <ISDELTA changed="false">true</ISDELTA>
        <MEASUREDATE changed="true">2018-02-04T14:35:59+00:00</MEASUREDATE>
        <MEASUREMENTID changed="true">10</MEASUREMENTID>
        <MEASUREMENTVALUE changed="false">1.051732E7</MEASUREMENTVALUE>
        <METERNAME changed="false">string</METERNAME>
        <POINTNUM changed="true">string</POINTNUM>
        <SITEID changed="false">string</SITEID>
      </METERDATA>
    </MXMETERDATASet>
</SyncMXMETERDATA>
```

The xsl I have written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns="http://http://www>w>org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:maximoMappings="local" exclude-
result_prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SyncMXMETERDATA xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" messageID="string">
        <MXMETERDATASet>
            <METERDATA>                        
                 <MEASUREMENTVALUE><xsl:value-of 
                 select="Notification[item/@name = 'Turbine1-Turbine OK Hours
                 Status']"/></MEASUREMENTVALUE>
                 <POINTNUM>GB1001</POINTNUM>
                 <DOROLLOVER changed="true">false</DOROLLOVER>
                 <ISDELTA changed="false">true</ISDELTA>
                 <MAXINTERRORMSG>string</MAXINTERRORMSG>
              </METERDATA>
          </MXMETERDATASet>
          </SyncMXMETERDATA>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I it is importing but I am not getting the data I require in the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your current (updated) XSLT the `xsl:stylesheet` contains the broken and not closed entry `xmlns="http://http://www>w>org/2001/XMLSchema`  Furthermore, the closing tag `</SyncMXMETERDATA>` is missing.
Following XSLT produces (almost) the desired ouput with the exception of `<max:MEASUREMENTVALUE>` and the `creationDateTime`-attribute as the item named `'Turbine1-Turbine OK Hours Status'` and the value for `creationDateTime` are not provided in the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns="http://www.3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:maximoMappings="local"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl maximoMappings">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <max:SyncMXMETERDATA xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
    baseLanguage="string" transLanguage="string" messageID="string" 
    maximoVersion="string">
      <max:MXMETERDATASet>
        <max:METERDATA action="Delete" relationship="string" 
                       ForInsert="string" transLanguage="string">
          <max:POINTNUM>GB1001</max:POINTNUM>
            <max:DOROLLOVER changed="true">false</max:DOROLLOVER>
            <max:ISDELTA changed="false">true</max:ISDELTA>
            <max:MAXINTERRORMSG>string</max:MAXINTERRORMSG>                        
          </max:METERDATA>
      </max:MXMETERDATASet>
    </max:SyncMXMETERDATA>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:SyncMXMETERDATA xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
     xmlns="http://www.3.org/2001/XMLSchema" baseLanguage="string"
     transLanguage="string" messageID="string" maximoVersion="string">
  <max:MXMETERDATASet>
     <max:METERDATA action="Delete" relationship="string" 
                    ForInsert="string" transLanguage="string">
       <max:POINTNUM>GB1001</max:POINTNUM>
       <max:DOROLLOVER changed="true">false</max:DOROLLOVER>
       <max:ISDELTA changed="false">true</max:ISDELTA>
       <max:MAXINTERRORMSG>string</max:MAXINTERRORMSG>
    </max:METERDATA>
  </max:MXMETERDATASet>
</max:SyncMXMETERDATA>
```

Another difference in the output is the `xmlns="http://www.3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` attribute for the `<max:SyncMXMETERDATA>`. If you don't want it in the output, you can delete `xmlns="http://www.3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` from the `<xsl:stylesheet>` definition.

Comment: Thanks for that I didn't realize I left the max in the desired format. I had gone back and changed the xsl to omit the max but forgot the output. There were some basic errors, but it took me quite some time to even get to that point. Thanks again matthias_h

Comment: @Eoin, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) matthias_h's answer if it's helped.  Thanks.